# ImportError: no module named urllib3, urllib3 is already installed

Tags: python, twilio, urllib3

Here is my code:

```
from twilio.rest import Client

# Your Account SID from twilio.com/console
account_sid = "sid"
# Your Auth Token from twilio.com/console
auth_token  = "token"

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(
    to="number", 
    from_="number",
    body="new phone who dis")

print(message.sid)
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mahika/Documents/sendtexttest.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twilio.rest import Client
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/twilio/rest/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-intel/egg/twilio/http/http_client.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests-2.18.4-py2.7.egg/requests/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
import urllib3
ImportError: No module named urllib3
```

The problem is that urllib3 is already installed. What should I do?

Comment: whats your python interpreter path? and where did you install `urllib3 `?

Comment: Here's my python path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

Comment: But how did you install `urllib3`? Can you import `urllib3` when you just fire up the Python interpreter?

Comment: How do I find out where urllib3 is installed on my machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you did not install the `urllib3` to the python interpreter path correctly.

You give your python interpreter in comment:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

> How do I find out where urllib3 is installed on my machine?

If you want to check where `urllib3` is installed on your machine, you can use this command to find it:

```
sudo find / -name urllib3
```

I recommend you to check whether you install the `urllib3` is installed in your current python interpreter by:

```
sudo find /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/site-packages -name urllib3
```

---

**EDIT**

If you want to install it there:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip install urllib3
```

Comment: Here is what I'm getting: sudo find / -name urllib3
Password:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3-1.22-py2.7.egg/urllib3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3
find: /private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles/Store: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/3q/8dnb4vgs02978lsdjrmz_wc00000gn/0/SafariFamily: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/3q/8dnb4vgs02978lsdjrmz_wc00000gn/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv: Operation not permitted

Comment: When checking if installed in current interpreter: sudo find /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/site-packages -name urllib3
Password:
find: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/site-packages: No such file or directory

Comment: So, this is the issue, you did not install the `urllib3 ` in your current python interpreter.

Comment: Thank you. How can I install it in my current python interpreter? And why would it have installed in the wrong place in the first place? I'm new to coding...

Comment: @MahikaGupta see my EDIT.